# Grammaticality and idiomaticity of "Help clarify"

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> An example could *help clarify* the problem.

I hear the construction *help clarify* quite often, is it idiomatic?

Comment: See this answer on the same question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3578/what-is-the-correct-way-to-use-infinitive-after-the-verb-help-with-or-without

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of *help* here is as a transitive verb, with the meaning "To contribute in some way to."

Help + verb is a common combination.

E.g.

> Doctors are finding one way that sugar can benefit your health: it may
>   *help heal* wounds when antibiotics fail.

or

> New mammogram guidelines could *help catch* breast cancer early.